# Proving that a language is not context-free

Tags: formal-languages, automata, context-free-grammar

> Given the language $$L = \{ a^p \mid p\, \text{IS NOT prime} \}$$ is $L$ Context free? If not, prove that it's not.

May I have some suggestions on how to use the pumping lemma to prove this, please?

Thanks.

Comment: Please show your working so far :)

Comment: I suggest using the pumping lemma to derive a contradiction. That's the way pumping lemmas are typically used to prove that languages don't fall into the relevant class.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you were asked to use necessarily the pumping lemma in order to solve the problem, but in this case of language, it is much easier to use [Parikh's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parikh%27s_theorem).

The alphabet of the language is $\Sigma=\{a\}$. So, for every word $w$, Parikh's vector is $P(w)=|w|_{a}$ (which is the number of occurences of $a$ in $w$). Then, the set of Parikh's vectors for language $L$ of the exercise is the set of divisible numbers. $$S=\{P(w):w\in L\}=\{|a^p|: p~\text{not prime}\}=\{p:p~\text{not prime}\}$$

It is easy to show that this set is not semi-linear, since no finite union of linear sets can result to $S$. If there was such a union, a divisible number would be missing, leading to contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

The pumping lemma can be used to solve this problem.

We need to show: for all claimed pumping lengths $p\in\mathbb{N}$, there is some string $s$ of length $\ge p$ that cannot be split into the shape $s=uvwxy, |vx|\ge 1, |vwx|\le p$ such that $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}: uv^nwx^ny\in L$.

Fix a "pumping length" $p$. Let $q$ be the least composite number that has no prime factor $\le p$ (it's worth saying that such a composite number exists: you could take $r$ to be the least prime $> p$ and then $r^2$ has no prime factor $\le p$, so $q\le r^2$ exists).

Take the string $s=a^q$. No matter what split $s=uvwxy$ occurs, observe that $uv^nwx^ny=a^{q+(n-1)|vx|}$ i.e. repeating $v,x$ will just correspond to adding $|vx|$-many characters $a$. Let $m:=|vx|$. As $a^q\in L$, we need to show that *some* string $a^{q+(n-1)m}$ is not in $L$.

So, our proof is complete if we can show that, in general, a sequence $q,q+m,q+2m,q+3m,\dots$ (for $q$ prime, $1\le p<q$) must contain a prime number in it.

[Dirichlet's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions) gives that every arithmetic sequence contains infinitely many primes if the first term and common difference are coprime. We chose $q$ to have no prime factors $\le p$, and $m\le |vwx|\le p$, so $q,m$ are coprime. Hence, $L$ is not context-free.

---

Just for interest, that $\bar{L}$ is also not context-free would require a similar statement, that a (slightly constrained) arithmetic sequence contains at least one non-prime, and in fact [this and a much stronger statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions) is also true, due to a different theorem sometimes also called "Dirichlet's theorem".

Answer (score 0):

Here is another proof:

- $\{a^p\mid p\in \mathbb{P}\}$ is not a context-free language. This can be proven using the pumping lemma, but the proof is easier than for $\{a^n\mid n\notin\mathbb{P}\}$. Basically, if $u = a^p = vwxyz$ is a decomposition, then $vw^{p+1}xy^{p+1}z = a^{p+p|wy|}$ and $p(1 +|wy|)$ is not prime.
- Context-free languages over unary alphabet are regular (this is another application of [Parikh's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parikh%27s_theorem), but see [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/40791/proving-that-any-cf-language-over-a-1-letter-alphabet-is-regular) for another proof).
- Regular languages are closed under complement.

Therefore, if $L = \{a^n\mid n\notin \mathbb{P}\}$ is context-free, then it is regular, and so is its complement $\{a^p\mid p\in \mathbb{P}\}$, but this is a contradiction.